# Como tratar as rotas do meu app com Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express.js

Gente, estou utilizando um framework para o front do meu app. Ele fica escutando e sempre que se clica em um link ele retorna a página via requisição Ajax.

Obs: estou usando o AngularJS. Com Angular eu posso tratar rotas, mas ele solicita o arquivo e injeta na view (me corrijam se falei besteira) e isso não é meu objetivo.

Link do framework css: http://goratchet.com/

Meu problema é: preciso que quando o usuário acesse rotas como `/user/:id` eu possa tratar essa rota e servir a página `user.html` e também possa acessar o `id` e montar a página no front recuperando os dados do usuário via `id`. Mas não consigo entender como usar o Express para isso.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do seu arquivo de configuração das rotas e no seu controler busque  `$stateParams.chatId`com isso vc pega o parâmetro vindo da url

```
$stateProvider.state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })



 angular.module('starter.controllers', []).controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
      $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
    })
```